# replace some row data by means in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, mean

I have a dataset from lab analyses, but it looks like there was an error in the lab for one sample as the data is quite different to all other data. I would like to take the mean of other replicates from the same sample to replace the "bad data."

This is what the data looks like now (notice the last row):

```
> Season    Location    Var1    Var2   Var3
> spring    here         12      14     12
> spring    here         13      13     16
> spring    here         11      15     12
> spring    there        13      11     14
> spring    there        12      12     13
> spring    there        15      14     15
> summer    here         12      14     12
> summer    here         13      13     16
> summer    here         11      15     12
> summer    there        13      11     14
> summer    there        12      12     13
> summer    there         5       4      5
```

And this is how I would like it to look (notice that the last row is the mean of the preceding two rows, which are replicates of the same sample):

```
> Season    Location    Var1    Var2   Var3
> spring    here         12      14     12
> spring    here         13      13     16
> spring    here         11      15     12
> spring    there        13      11     14
> spring    there        12      12     13
> spring    there        15      14     15
> summer    here         12      14     12
> summer    here         13      13     16
> summer    here         11      15     12
> summer    there        13      11     14
> summer    there        12      12     13
> summer    there        12.5    11.5   13.5
```

I have tried a few things including `Reduce()`, `aggregate()`, and `merge()`, but I'm finding it difficult to remove the data from the final row and replace it with the mean from the previous two rows while keeping the `Season` and `Location` variables.

Comment: So your problem is to (i) find outliers and (ii) replace these with mean of other values in same group? Or just the second one? In that case I would like to know how you'd find the outliers?

Comment: This is quite a small dataset, so the outliers are obvious when we look at the data. I hadn't thought that we would need a rule to define the outliers.

Comment: I mean to change the values of any row one will need that rows' ids.  In this case you want to replace values in specific column of those rows only? Let me give a few minutes I'll tell you how.

Answer (score 0):

dput of data say (season) is

```
> dput(season)
structure(list(Season = c("spring", "spring", "spring", "spring", 
"spring", "spring", "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", "summer", 
"summer"), Location = c("here", "here", "here", "there", "there", 
"there", "here", "here", "here", "there", "there", "there"), 
    Var1 = c(12L, 13L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 15L, 12L, 13L, 11L, 13L, 
    12L, 5L), Var2 = c(14L, 13L, 15L, 11L, 12L, 14L, 14L, 13L, 
    15L, 11L, 12L, 4L), Var3 = c(12L, 16L, 12L, 14L, 13L, 15L, 
    12L, 16L, 12L, 14L, 13L, 5L), row_id = 1:12), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))

# A tibble: 12 x 6
   Season Location  Var1  Var2  Var3 row_id
   <chr>  <chr>    <int> <int> <int>  <int>
 1 spring here        12    14    12      1
 2 spring here        13    13    16      2
 3 spring here        11    15    12      3
 4 spring there       13    11    14      4
 5 spring there       12    12    13      5
 6 spring there       15    14    15      6
 7 summer here        12    14    12      7
 8 summer here        13    13    16      8
 9 summer here        11    15    12      9
10 summer there       13    11    14     10
11 summer there       12    12    13     11
12 summer there        5     4     5     12
```

Clear enough as you have already identified outlier rows, I have created an row_id column in the dataframe so that the values can be replaced there. Proceed as follows.

```
# First store all such rows in a vector v1

v1 <- c(12)

#Proceed for replacement

library(tidyverse)

season %>% group_by(Season, Location) %>%
  mutate(var1 = ifelse(row_id %in% v1, NA, Var1),
         Var1 = ifelse(is.na(var1), mean(var1, na.rm = T), Var1),
         var2 = ifelse(row_id %in% v1, NA, Var2),
         Var2 = ifelse(is.na(var2), mean(var2, na.rm = T), Var2),
         var3 = ifelse(row_id %in% v1, NA, Var3),
         Var3 = ifelse(is.na(var3), mean(var3, na.rm = T), Var3)) %>%
  select(-var1, -var2, -var3) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 12 x 6
   Season Location  Var1  Var2  Var3 row_id
   <chr>  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <int>
 1 spring here      12    14    12        1
 2 spring here      13    13    16        2
 3 spring here      11    15    12        3
 4 spring there     13    11    14        4
 5 spring there     12    12    13        5
 6 spring there     15    14    15        6
 7 summer here      12    14    12        7
 8 summer here      13    13    16        8
 9 summer here      11    15    12        9
10 summer there     13    11    14       10
11 summer there     12    12    13       11
12 summer there     12.5  11.5  13.5     12
```